# complex mapping with automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have a complex object (returned from a web service api).  It has multiple nested items, some of which contain lists of property names & values (key value pairs).
for example

a meterdetail class can contain multiple meter objects, each meter object has multiple rows, each row has a key (the property name) and a value (the propertyvalue).  I need to map each row to a specific property of a class, so

1. row 1  key 'core' value maps to the 'Core' property of my meter class
2. row 2 key 'serial_number' value maps to the SerialNumber property of my
   meter class
3. row 3 key 'install_date' value maps to the InstallDate property of my
   meter class

and so on

is this possible with automapper ? If so, how would I do this ?
Im using .netcore 5 and C#
Id greatly appreciate some advice

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother. AutoMapper's great for simple 1-1 mappings from one type to another where they look basically the same, but if you did manage to do what you're asking with AutoMapper, you'd just be hiding complex logic in a mapping class away from where things are happening. If it were me, I'd spend the time literally just doing it by hand, instead. You'll thank yourself for it later, I imagine.

Comment: 100% this - in the past I've inherited projects with very complex mappings and I always end up removing and replacing with a manually method.

Comment: That was my original plan, I thought if it was straightforward with automapper Id give it a go and it might save me a lot of work.  To be honest, trying to find a way to do it with automapper is probably taking longer than coding it myself :-)